# A question about complex integral: $\int_{|z| = 1}\frac{1}{z^{2}\sin z}\,dz.$

Tags: complex-integration

I am stuck computing the following complex integral
$$\int_{|z| = 1}\frac{1}{z^{2}\sin z}\,dz.$$
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Use the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem). The integrand is a meromorphic function which has a [pole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_(complex_analysis)) of order $3$ at $0$ inside the closed simple path $|z|=1$:
$$\int_{|z| = 1}\frac{1}{z^{2}\sin z}\,dz=2\pi i\cdot\mbox{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^{2}\sin z},0\right).$$
In order to evaluate the [residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)), note that $\sin z=z-z^3/6+o(z^3)$ and therefore
$$\frac{1}{z^{2}\sin z}=\frac{1}{z^{2}(z-z^3/6+o(z^3))}=
\frac{1}{z^{3}(1-z^2/6+o(z^2))}=\frac{1+z^2/6+o(z^2)}{z^{3}}.$$

Comment: @Good boy You are welcome!